# Debezium connector for MySQL - different sets of tables for initial snapshot and ongoing CDC

Tags: mysql, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using Debezium connector for MySQL with Kakfa. So my schema changes and data changes go into kafka topcs.

I'm trying to see if the following behaviour can be achieved without manual intervention.

I'm wanting to have only one table as part of the `snapshot.mode=initial` snapshot.
Then I want multiple tables to be monitored for ongoing CDC.

https://debezium.io/documentation/reference/stable/connectors/mysql.html seems to list separate options for snapshot and cdc tables so I have assumed the following is possible in my connector config:

```
...
 "table.include.list": "api.table1, api.table2",
 "snapshot.include.collection.list": "api.table1",
...
```

The snapshot completes for table1 and then CDC changes are picked up for table1. My kakfa `schema-changes` topic also shows the schema for table1.

However when I make a change to data in table2 I get the Kafka Connector error:

`Caused by: io.debezium.DebeziumException: Encountered change event for table api.table2 whose schema isn't known to this connector`

Is this behaviour supported or do I need to do this manually in steps?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you only want one table to be snapshot, I think it would be safer to just make two separate json configs

Comment: ok many thanks for your time  - does this mean I was incorrect with my initial assumption?

Comment: I haven't really used Debezium. I think when you use initial snapshot mode, it'll always try to snapshot all included tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also posted on the debezium@googlegroups.com lists and was kindly told that this was a known issue. Between then and now a fix has been released. Many thanks to the debezium team! :)

https://issues.redhat.com/browse/DBZ-3952